# Controller Not Firing When Using URL Param

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm not clear why this isn't functioning. The rest of my code - sans the URL Param-based routing is working fine, I've tested that all. However, when I tried to include a URL argument in my url (base.url/route/:param) the '.otherwise' element of my routeProvider is firing instead of the appropriate controller designated in the routeProvider.

Here's the relevant bits of code:

module.config

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
//http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07
$routeProvider
    .when('/home',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
    .when('/implementation-reference/:ref-scope',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/topic_tpl.html',
            controller: 'ImplReference'
        })
    .when('/projects',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/project_list_tpl.html',
            controller: 'Projects'
        })
    .when ('/site-help',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/site-help.html'
        })
    .otherwise(
        {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/404.html'
        })
});
```

module.controller

```
app.controller('ImplReference', function($scope, $routeParams) {
alert('hi');    
});
```

I get my 404 page when going to /implementation-reference/whatever.

Any ideas why I don't see the alert I put at the beginning of my controller, nor see any errors in the console?

Comment: I believe the url should be `#/implementation-reference/whatever`

Comment: where is `getAllTooicPosts`?

Comment: @Chandermani, why do I need to add that hash? It's there is the actual URL in the browser, but all my other routes in the routeProvider run fine in the above, they don't need that hash added.

Comment: Guess I should have cleaned this up. Just consider the controller and the alert. I have tried the same, removing the factory dependency (formsImplReference), and I still can't get the controller to fire and show me that alert. It still routes to .otherwise from the RouteProvider.

Comment: How are you navigating to this url, from js or html?

Comment: I am navigating from a url in the browser, or I might expect them to enter it into the address bar: <a href="#/implementation-reference/business">Business Reference</a>

Comment: If you look at the RouteProvider I show above, when the user arrives at /projects then the controller specified fires fine.

Comment: I figured it out. I can't have a dash in the param value in the RouteProvider. I will post more detail tomorrow once Stack Overflow lets me post an answer to my own question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell, the issue lay in use a dash in the param as defined in RouteProvider. I originally had:

```
.when('/implementation-reference/:ref-scope',
    {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/topic_tpl.html',
        controller: 'ImplReference'
    })
```

when I changed it to this:

```
.when('/implementation-reference/:ref',
    {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/topic_tpl.html',
        controller: 'ImplReference'
    })
```

...suddenly everything works fine.

I noticed this after adding a controller to the 'otherwise' that showed me the $route information. After drilling through it, I saw that the regex on the pre-defined route which had the param was only working on the part before the dash.

I've been mystified by this for hours, and can't imagine how this isn't documented more clearly somewhere. Perhaps this is some newbie mistake (I am new to this).